# Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate some random standard normal variables and correlate them
In particular I want:

[image: eq1]

where [image: Y...] is the vector I want to simulate, and [image: sigma]  the given covariance matrix.

I am doing the following in matlab:

1. Simulate a vector of uncorrelated Gaussian random variables, [image: Z]
2. then find a square root of [image: Sigma], i.e. a matrix [image: C] such that [image: eq6].

Then the target vector is given by

[image: eq7]

Here is my matlab code:

```
N = 500000
u_1 = normrnd(zeros(N,1),1);
u_2 = normrnd(zeros(N,1),1);
u_3 = normrnd(zeros(N,1),1);
u_4 = normrnd(zeros(N,1),1);

rv = [u_1 '; u_2'; u_3'; u_4'];


VarCov = [1 -0.87 0.0 -0.6;
          -0.87 1 0.0 0.0;
          0.0 0.0 1 0.0
          -0.6 0.0 0.0 1];

ch = chol(VarCov);
result = ch * rv;
```

However the `chol(VarCov)` is giving an error saying that the matrix is not positive semi definite.

Comment: Thank you pseudoDust.

Comment: No problem, it's annoying that SO does not support latex, although there are [reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on). in any case, I use [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) site to generate images.

Comment: Maybe it's not positive semi definite?

Comment: I know. But still is a variance covariance matrix, so I should be able to do this ...

Comment: OK, but is your actual question "how do I generate a random vector with a negative-definite covariance matrix?" ?

Comment: No. My question is, if I have a VarCov matrix which is not positive semi-definite, is there any way to still be able to correlate the standard random normal variables?

Comment: A non positive semi-definite cov matrix is an indication that you have specified correlations that do not make sense, and that a series cannot be generated to give that cov.  For instance mat = [1 0.9 0.8;0.9 1 -0.5;0.8 -0.5 1] indicates that A is highly correlated with both B and C, but that B and C are negatively correlated.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: covarience is like probability negative makes no sense unless extremely rare cases.